# VBScript Text-To-Speech (to text)

Tags: vbscript

I made a very simple text-to-speech program using VBScript (which I have limited experience with). It simply opens a command prompt, you type something, and Windows spvoice speaks the message.

I want this app to take the message input and add that text to a separate .txt file. So basically, this would be text-to-speech-to-text. Is VBScript too limited to read and write to text file?

```
Dim message, sapi
  message=InputBox("Enter text:","Enter Text")
  Set sapi=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
  sapi.Speak message
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following to write the message to a text file.

```
Set objFileToWrite = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile _ 
("C:\SpeechMessage.txt",2,true)
objFileToWrite.WriteLine(message)
objFileToWrite.Close
Set objFileToWrite = Nothing
```

[VBScript Text Files: Read, Write, Append](http://eddiejackson.net/wp/?p=8619)

**EDIT:**

Create the following to avoid permissions issues on the root of C:

```
C:\Speech\
```

And Try this code that will create the file if it does not exist and append to it if it does.

```
Set objFileToWrite = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFileToWrite.FileExists("C:\Speech\Message.txt")  then
       Set objFileToWrite = objFileToWrite.OpenTextFile("C:\Speech\SpeechMessage.txt",8,true)
Else 
      Set objFileToWrite = objFileToWrite.CreateTextFile("C:\Speech\SpeechMessage.txt")   
End If 
objFileToWrite.WriteLine(message)
objFileToWrite.Close
Set objFileToWrite = Nothing
```

Comment: I'm getting a "permission denied" error. Would i have to run as administrator?

Comment: to be more specific, i'm getting 800A0046 error

Comment: @Nikolajs in this case the VBS does not create the file, can you confirm `C:\SpeechMessage.txt` exists and that you have full permissions to access it?

Comment: the file does exist and it should have full permissions

Comment: @Nikolajs I think the issue is that it is on the root of the `C:` try creating the folder `C:\Speech` and using that.

Comment: Why don't you suggest relative paths (which are almost always writable)?

Comment: that seemed to work. weird that it wasn't working before

Comment: @iBug I agree that would be a good solution as well to avoid permission issues.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work. I was running into issues with 800A0046 error at first. To fix this, I made a new folder in the C: drive and rooted to that.

```
Dim message, sapi, objFileToWrite

message=InputBox("What do you want me to say?","Speak to Me")
Set sapi=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
sapi.Speak message

Set objFileToWrite = 
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
_.OpenTextFile("C:\Speech\LiveChat.txt",2,true)
objFileToWrite.WriteLine(message)
objFileToWrite.Close
Set objFileToWrite = Nothing
```